# What's an expression that means bringing something to where it can be seen or used?

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm specifically thinking of in a public service context. Say there is a resource that exists but no one knows about it or makes use of it, so instead of waiting for the people to come to the resource, we bring the resource to where the people already are. Is there an expression for that?

This doesn't really capture the meaning, but I'm thinking it would be phrased sort of like the opposite of "leading a horse to water" but instead, we are "bringing water to a horse."

Answer (score 2):

"Shine a light on" can be used to call attention to something that has been kept in the dark, so to speak.

Another is "bring to the fore / forefront", unburying it

"Bring to light" is simple and effective

Answer (score 0):

The phrase, "bringing water to a horse." sort of makes sense to me, I think you were on to something there. Perhaps, "bringing the trough directly to the cattle".